# Prestashop Import/Export with custom fields

Tags: csv, import, export, prestashop

I have parts store and I have added a custom field in each part to tell its compatible models and brands. I want to export product(parts) data with this custom field and after updating my data I want to import it back with the same custom field. Is there any way or module available for this?

Answer (score 1):

if you add your custom field properly and its working fine (add/edit) then you can easily add it in import/export file.

**For add custom field in export csv:**

Prestashop By default does not export any more information except than which are display in Product list.

that list are called **fields_list** in prestashop.

Check `controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php file`

Around line 200, you will find how **fields_list** are generated

with starting of

```
$this->fields_list = array();
```

Above that code, you will find some sql queries which will get necessary products data by joining with various tables.

you can add other parameters in select query.

i add **wholesale_price** in select query to export wholesale_price for all products.

```
$this->_select .= 'shop.`name` AS `shopname`, a.`wholesale_price`, a.`id_shop_default`, ';
```

Now this **fields_list** will display in product listing and will also display in CSV export.

No need to write extra code to add **fields_list** in export CSV file.

**For add custom field in import csv:**

add your custom field in `controllers/admin/AdminImportController.php`

in **available_fields** array.

Find case `$this->entities[$this->l('Products')]:`

below that case you will find

```
$this->available_fields = array
```

add your custom field name there (same name in DB field name)

Now, when you click on import button that new field will available for import product operation.

Answer (score 0):

I've looking for something similar and I didn't found.
But why you couldn't handle this this using attributes and combinations ?

Comment: Actually this is my clients request and he already has custom fields. Not feasible to suggest move all his data to attributes first then do import/export.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the extension to import/export customized fields in PrestaShop, you can try Store Manager for PrestaShop.

It is not free, but there is version you can use without limits for a month, so in case you cope within this time frame there is no need to pay  - 
https://www.prestashopmanager.com/free-download/

Here is tutorial - https://www.prestashopmanager.com/useful-articles/tips-tricks/how-to-add-product-customized-fields-to-multiple-products/

Comment: I don't need it for one time only. This will be ongoing process since new products come in and sold out products got our from store.